# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by user code , Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have read the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx, about how i can authenticate asp.net mvc users from multiple domains, so inside my asp.net mvc i did the following :-

I added the following to my web.config:-

```
<system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="ad-domainA.intra\it360ad.user" connectionPassword="$$$$$" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
```

&

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ad-domainA.intra/CN=Users,DC=ad-domainA,DC=intra" />
```

and i added the following Account.controller:-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {


            MembershipProvider domainProvider;

            domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];


            // Validate the user with the membership system.
            if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
                {

                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
                        model.UserName, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If there is no RequestUrl query string attribute, just set
                    // the authentication cookie. Provide navigation on the login page
                    // to pages that require authentication, or user can use browser
                    // to navigate to protected pages.
                    // Set second parameter to false so cookie is not persistent
                    // across sessions.
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                }
            }
            else
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

        }
```

but when i type my user name and password inside the login screen and click on enter , i got the following error:-

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by
>   user code   HResult=-2146232062   Message=Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Web, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>   (C:\Users\john.john\Desktop\test login\TMS\TMS\web.config line 39)
>   Source=System.Web   BareMessage=Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one
>   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Filename=C:\Users\john.john\Desktop\test login\TMS\TMS\web.config
>   Line=39   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
>          at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Providers()   InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>          HResult=-2147024894
>          Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>          Source=mscorlib
>          FileName=System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>          FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = AD-ITSERVICES\john.john LOG: DisplayName = System.Web,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Partial) WRN:
>   Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly: WRN:
>   Assembly Name: System.Web, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a | Domain ID: 4 WRN: A partial bind
>   occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided. WRN:
>   This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly. WRN: It
>   is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the
>   assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and
>   public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/john.john/Desktop/test login/TMS/TMS/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = C:\Users\john.john\Desktop\test login\TMS\TMS\bin
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\john.john\Desktop\test
>   login\TMS\TMS\web.config LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\john.john\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/john.john/AppData/Local/Temp/2/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/2fc69b03/2c0137b8/System.Web.DLL. LOG: Attempting download
>   of new URL file:///C:/Users/john.john/AppData/Local/Temp/2/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/2fc69b03/2c0137b8/System.Web/System.Web.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/john.john/Desktop/test
>   login/TMS/TMS/bin/System.Web.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/john.john/Desktop/test
>   login/TMS/TMS/bin/System.Web/System.Web.DLL. LOG: Attempting download
>   of new URL file:///C:/Users/john.john/AppData/Local/Temp/2/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/2fc69b03/2c0137b8/System.Web.EXE. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/john.john/AppData/Local/Temp/2/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/2fc69b03/2c0137b8/System.Web/System.Web.EXE. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/john.john/Desktop/test
>   login/TMS/TMS/bin/System.Web.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/john.john/Desktop/test
>   login/TMS/TMS/bin/System.Web/System.Web.EXE.
>
> ```
>    StackTrace:
>         at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> ```
>
> StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>               at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)
>               at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
>               at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
>               at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement,
>   XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
>          InnerException:

on the following line of code inside the Account controller:-

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {MembershipProvider domainProvider;
domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
```

so what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

For this declaration of System.Web

```
System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

The version is also needed (4.0 right?)

```
Version=4.0.0.0
```

Comment: thanks i added the version and the exception is not raised, but currently users will always get the following message "The user name or password provided is incorrect." when they try to login ? can you advice why the authorization will always fail ?

Comment: and i am not sure if the PublicKeyToken number i provided (b03f5f7f11d50a3a) is correct, or i should use other number ?

Comment: I have modified my connection string to include the server IP as follow:- <add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://10.211.152.31.ad-domainA.intra/CN=Users,DC=ad-domainA,DC=intra" /> . but now i am getting the following error:- Unable to establish secure connection with the server

Comment: Public key is correct for 4.0.0.0, from what I read.  It seems like the previous setup worked better: did the user put in their domain as in `DOMAIN\USER`?  You could also try creating a custom provider that inherits from ADProvider, override the methods that do the validation, and then debug it yourself...

Comment: i added the attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" to my provider , and i removed the version and public key token. so my provider became:-  <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="....." connectionPassword="......" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/> . and it is working well !!?

Comment: OK, so it infers it most likely since it is an MS DLL...  didn't know that, at least it works :-D